# how to save data that is generated via for loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab, save, dataset, createfile

i need a way to save data that is generated via for loops.To simply explain,first I generate a matrix 5*10-in the second iteration the process repeat and another matrix 5*10 is generated(** note that maybe some rows need to be empty)(i mean in second iteration row3 is empty) and the second matrix should concat the first one and make 5*20 matrix.It is possible in excel.but i need the faster way to save data? which of table/dataset/... can be used????

```
[data,header] = xlsread('E:\TEST\chozen_font_data.xlsx','font');
font_data = data(:,1);
a = 'C:\Users\S.R.P\Desktop\ouput';
A = dir(fullfile(a));
isub = [A(:).isdir];
nameFolds = {A(isub).name}';
nameFolds(ismember(nameFolds,{'.','..'})) = [];

for n_fol = 1:numel(nameFolds)
  name_sub_fold = dir(fullfile(a,nameFolds{n_fol},'*.png'));
  for n_sub = 1: numel( name_sub_fold )
     [~,~,image] = 
     imread(fullfile(a,nameFolds{n_fol},name_sub_fold(n_sub).name));
     image=im2bw(image);
     [ image ] = Crop_AroundAllComponent( image );
     name_font = regexprep(name_sub_fold(n_sub).name,'[^0-9]','');
     co = find( font_data == str2num( name_font)); 
     area  = area_calculation( image );
     md = matrix_density_calculation( image );
     [ num ] = DisconnectedComponent_calc( image );
     d={area,md,num};
     [s,m] = xlswrite('E:\TEST\chozen_font_data.xlsx', d, 'font', 
     strcat('GB',num2str(co)));
     end
     end
```

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate 2 matrices in matlab, you can just use square bracket concatenation notation. Like so:

```
row1 = zeros(10, 5);   % 10 by 5 row
row2 = ones(10, 5);    % another 10 by 5 row
total = [row1; row2];  % 20 by 5 combination
```

If you wanted to do this with for loops, you could add a new row with each iteration. For example:

```
start = 0;
end = 5;
result = [];
for i = start:end
    row = ...        % get the new row here
    result = [result; row];
end
```

Comment: it is not my answer